# Game of war that never ends

Tags: c++

Hello all I'm trying to write a game of war but my code produces games that never end. When I look at the output I see that there is a cycle where player one and player two alternate winning rounds. The evaluation of who should be winning looks correct. It almost seems like player one and player two's hands a evenly matched. I'm shuffling before the start of the game so I don't see how this could be possible. I'm not sure what's going on here. Also I'm using c++ 98.

```
using namespace std;

#define SSTR( x ) static_cast< std::ostringstream & >( \
        ( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

void shuffleDeck(vector<string> &);

void splitDeck(vector<string> vDeck, vector<string> &, vector<string> &);

int compareRound(char, char);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
vector<string> vPlayerOneCards;
vector<string> vPlayerTwoCards;

vector<string> vDeck;
for (int i = 2; i < 15; i++){
    for (int e = 0; e < 4; e++){
        string currentCard;
        if (i < 11){
            currentCard += SSTR( i ).c_str();
        }
        else if (i == 11){
            currentCard += "Jack";
        }
        else if (i == 12){
            currentCard += "Queen";
        }
        else if (i == 13){
            currentCard += "King";
        }
        else if (i == 14){
            currentCard += "Ace";
        }

        currentCard += " of ";

        if (e == 0){
            currentCard += "Hearts";
        }
        else if (e == 1){
            currentCard += "Diamonds";
        }
        else if (e == 2){
            currentCard += "Clubs";
        }
        else if (e == 3){
            currentCard += "Spades";
        }
        vDeck.push_back(currentCard);
    }
}

shuffleDeck(vDeck);

splitDeck(vDeck, vPlayerOneCards, vPlayerTwoCards);

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    cout << vPlayerOneCards[i] << endl;
}

cout << endl << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    cout << vPlayerTwoCards[i] << endl;
}

// This is the pile of cards that the winner of the round get's to keep.
vector<string> cardPool;
int counter = 0;
while (vPlayerOneCards.size() > 0 && vPlayerTwoCards.size() > 0){
    counter++;
    cardPool.push_back(vPlayerTwoCards[0]);
    cardPool.push_back(vPlayerOneCards[0]);

    cout << "Player One: " + vPlayerOneCards[0] + "." << endl << "VS" << endl << "Player Two: " + vPlayerTwoCards[0] + "." << endl;

    int roundWinner = compareRound(vPlayerOneCards[0][0], vPlayerTwoCards[0][0]);
    if (roundWinner == 0){
        cout << "Player One Wins The Round." << endl;
        while (cardPool.size() > 0){
            vPlayerOneCards.push_back(cardPool[cardPool.size()-1]);
            cardPool.erase(cardPool.end());
        }
    }
    else if (roundWinner == 1){
        cout << "Player Two Wins The Round." << endl;
        while (cardPool.size() > 0){
            vPlayerTwoCards.push_back(cardPool[cardPool.size()-1]);
            cardPool.erase(cardPool.end());
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Round Is A Tie." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    vPlayerOneCards.erase(vPlayerOneCards.begin());
    vPlayerTwoCards.erase(vPlayerTwoCards.begin());
    cout << vPlayerOneCards.size() << endl;
    cout << vPlayerTwoCards.size() << endl;
}

if (vPlayerOneCards.size() > 0){
    cout << "Player One Wins The Game Of WAR!!!!!";
}
else {
    cout << "Player Two Wins The Game Of WAR!!!!!";
}

return 0;
}

void shuffleDeck(vector<string> &vDeck){
    srand(time(0));
    random_shuffle(vDeck.begin(), vDeck.end());
}

void splitDeck(vector<string> vDeck, vector<string> &vPlayerOneCards, vector<string> &vPlayerTwoCards){
    for (int i = 1; i < 53; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            vPlayerOneCards.push_back(vDeck[i-1]);
        }
        else {
            vPlayerTwoCards.push_back(vDeck[i-1]);
        }
    }
}

int compareRound(char p1, char p2){
    char cArr[] = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'};
    vector<char> cardPrecedence(cArr, cArr + sizeof(cArr) / sizeof(cArr[0]) );
    int p1Precedence = distance(cardPrecedence.begin(), find(cardPrecedence.begin(), cardPrecedence.end(), p1));
    int p2Precedence = distance(cardPrecedence.begin(), find(cardPrecedence.begin(), cardPrecedence.end(), p2));
    if (p1Precedence > p2Precedence){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (p2Precedence > p1Precedence){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea of course. I wouldn't ask the question unless I needed help.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people that ask here don't even know what debugging is. And reading over your description again, I can see that you have looked it over. Sorry.

Comment: It's cool I know what you mean.

Comment: O please ignore the  "&& counter < 100" within the while (vPlayerOneCards.size() > 0 && vPlayerTwoCards.size() > 0 && counter < 100){ I ment to take that out. I'm going to edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was adding cards to the winners hand before I was removing the two cards being played in the round. After changing this functionality every thing started working correctly.

```
    cardPool.push_back(vPlayerTwoCards[0]);
    cardPool.push_back(vPlayerOneCards[0]);
    vPlayerOneCards.erase(vPlayerOneCards.begin());
    vPlayerTwoCards.erase(vPlayerTwoCards.begin());

    cout << "Player One: " + vPlayerOneCards[0] + "." << endl << "VS" << endl << "Player Two: " + vPlayerTwoCards[0] + "." << endl;

    int roundWinner = compareRound(vPlayerOneCards[0][0], vPlayerTwoCards[0][0]);
    if (roundWinner == 0){
        cout << "Player One Wins The Round." << endl;
        while (cardPool.size() > 0){
            vPlayerOneCards.push_back(cardPool[cardPool.size()-1]);
            cardPool.erase(cardPool.end());
        }
    }
    else if (roundWinner == 1){
        cout << "Player Two Wins The Round." << endl;
        while (cardPool.size() > 0){
            vPlayerTwoCards.push_back(cardPool[cardPool.size()-1]);
            cardPool.erase(cardPool.end());
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "The Round Is A Tie." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << vPlayerOneCards.size() << endl;
    cout << vPlayerTwoCards.size() << endl;
```

Comment: Accept your own answer so the question stops getting bumped. :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't login for a few days. :)